# Check for empty element in array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Similar to something I posted recently but not the same :-)

I'm trying to test in GAS if an array contains any empty values. `includes()` doesn't seem to be supported so I've been trying to use index but failing miserably. My test code is below with the empty element before 7

```
  var e = [1,2,3,4,2,4,,7];
  var x = 0;
  if (e.indexOf() ==-1){
    var x = 'No blanks';
  }
```

But no matter what I try it always passes. I've already tried `indexOf("")`, `indexOf('')` & `indexOf()`.

I've run out of things to try so any help would be greatly received!

Comment: consider using a conditional `Array#push` instead of assigning with the bracket operator and an index. i.e. `if (val !== undefined) {myArr.push(val)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there is a *spare array*. The missing element there isn't the empty string, it's just not there at all. Because the missing element there isn't enumerable either, it won't show up when you use array methods like `indexOf`. You might check to see whether the number of keys is equal to the `length` of the array:

```js
var e = [1,2,3,4,2,4,,7];
var x = Object.keys(e).length === e.length
  ? 'OK!'
  : 'Blank element detected';
console.log(x);

// constrast with a normal array:

e = [1,2,3,4,2,4,7];
x = Object.keys(e).length === e.length
  ? 'OK!'
  : 'Blank element detected';
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Ah. Think I misread the output of the logger. So am I right in saying it would actually be `, ,` ie with a space?

Comment: No, nothing is there at all - it's not a space, nor is it the empty string. For it to be a space, it would have to be enclosed in string delimiters, like `' '` or `" "`.

Comment: spare? or sparse?

Comment: Ah. OK. Well your code did the trick nicely. Thanks. I didn't realise you could use keys with arrays?

Comment: @ChrisBarrett everything in JavaScript is an object. `Object.keys()` will thusly work (there are perhaps some fun exceptions regarding `null` and `undefined`).

Comment: @ChrisBarrett Yep, this is one of the very few times where it would be useful. You'd almost always want to use the array methods instead. (Though, ideally, you'd never be working with sparse arrays to begin with)

Answer (score 0):

To find the keys of all empty elements if there any:

```js
var e = [1,,3,4,2,,7];

var o = Object.keys(e);

m = [];

o.forEach(function(e,i){
    if(i>0 && e-o[i-1]>1){
        m.push(e-1) 
    }
})

console.log(m);

console.log(m.length);
```

Comment: No arrows in Apps Script, unfortunately. And shouldn't you use `forEach` instead of `map`?

Comment: @tehhowch I didn't know that about Apps Script. and forEach.. it's the same in this case I guess I'm iterating the keys, why do you think is better forEach?

Comment: Consider a large array - `map` returns an equivalent-size array. In your case it is discarded immediately, but it is still created (and every index is `undefined`).  `forEach` invokes a callback just like `map`, but there is no return value.

Comment: @tehhowch Ok, in this case is definitely better `forEach`, thank you for the enlightenment.